# In Spring How to send email with attachments to multiple users

Tags: java, spring, email

I am using spring & Java based application. I just need to send reports to users periodically .I have done this by using JavaMailSender and velocity and Jobscheduler.

But I need to send reports to multi recipients  at onetime. Does any one know that How to send email to multi recipients without showing other recipients who has received the same email by using spring framework ?

Comment: yes you can iterate the userlist and send them one by one.for atachment you have to use JavaMailSender instead of MailSender to send attachments, and attach the resources with MimeMessageHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class **MimeMessageHelper** frequently used with JavaMailSender exist a method named setBcc()... This method received how to parameter objects InternetAddress or String arrays.

Besides you can use in class MimeMessage the method addRecipient indicating Message.RecipientType.BCC

Check official [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#addRecipients%28javax.mail.Message.RecipientType,%20javax.mail.Address%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Either send multiple copies or use `Bcc`, just like for any other mass e-mail.